# Db2Service issue-spring Cloud foundry

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-connectors

I am having an issue while connecting db2 service in the cloud foundry. I have created the service as **cf cups db2service -p "jdbcUrl,user,password"**.While deploying the application on cloud I am facing a **class cast exception** and also **no suitable connector found** exception.The below is my configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@ServiceScan
@Profile("cloud")
public class Db2CloudConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource db2servicenew() {

        CloudFactory cloudFactory = new CloudFactory();
        Cloud cloud = cloudFactory.getCloud();
        DB2ServiceInfo db2ServiceInfo= (DB2ServiceInfo) cloud.getServiceInfo("db2servicenew"); 
        return cloud.getServiceConnector(db2ServiceInfo.getId(), DataSource.class, null);

    }

    @Bean(name = "db2JdbcTemplate") 
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource db2servicenew) { 
        return new JdbcTemplate(db2servicenew); 
    } 

}
```

I have also added the below dependencies in my gradle file.

```
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:1.2.0.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector:1.2.0.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-core:1.2.0.RELEASE")
```

Can you please help me with this issue.

Comment: Please show the details of the class cast exception with the stack trace. You can also run "gradle dependencies" and share relevant parts of that output to make sure you are actually getting version 1.2.0.RELEASE of the Connectors libraries (sometimes gradle will choose other versions).

Comment: 2016-02-22T03:47:10.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No suitable ServiceConnectorCreator found: service id=db2servicenew, service info type=org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo, connector type=interface javax.sql.DataSource

Comment: What about the details of the ClassCastException? And what is the value you provided for the "jdbcUrl" key in the credentials?

Comment: I have given the url format as "jdbc:db2://<host>:<port>/<database_name>".The class cast exception i get is " Sat Feb 20 2016 15:44:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) [App/0] OUT Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo cannot be cast to org.springframework.cloud.service.common.DB2ServiceInfo "

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo cannot be cast to org.springframework.cloud.service.common.DB2ServiceInfo` exception, it appears to me that you aren't getting the Connectors dependencies you think you are getting.

To confirm this, run the `gradle :dependencies` task and see what versions you are actually getting. The relevant part of the output of that task should look something like this:

```
+--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector: -> 1.2.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-core:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.4.RELEASE -> 4.1.7.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector: -> 1.2.0.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-core:1.2.0.RELEASE
```

If my hunch is correct, you might instead see something in the output like `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:1.2.0.RELEASE -> 1.1.1.RELEASE (*)`, indicating that gradle is choosing to use an older version that what you've asked it to based on other transitive dependencies. I've seen this happen with Spring Boot apps, as Boot pulls in an older version of Connectors.

If you do see that version downgrade, you should look at pulling in the [Spring propdeps](https://github.com/spring-projects/gradle-plugins/tree/master/propdeps-plugin) plugin for gradle to get the dependencies straight.

If this isn't the problem, then you will need to share a sample project that demonstrates this problem.